# How to enable CLR on a remote SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, configuration, sql-clr

I have been created a dll for SQL Server 2014 to add some custom functions for my stored procedures for my asp.net websites.

I don't have any problem in the local server but can't enable the CLR features on a remote host database; trying to do so throws an error that User does not have permission to perform this action.

So I call host administrative and they told me I can use only virtual servers or personal server to enable this feature. But virtual servers monthly charges and personal servers are very expensive.

So I want to know to are there anyways exist to add dll to the remote host and using them somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLCLR, or technically the "CLR enabled" server configuration option, is a Server-level option, not Database-level. Since it sounds like you are using shared hosting with no server-level permissions, then the answer is just what the sysadmins told you: No.

Now, if you can convince them to enable it for everyone on the server, then you would be able to do this.

Or, you could possibly consider using SQL Server on Amazon RDS which allows for SQLCLR (`SAFE` Assemblies only -- I have successfully installed and used [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/) on [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing/)) and *should* have options that are not cost-prohibitive (though I don't know your specific requirements, but worth taking a quick look as they do have a "free" tier).